# After I created 2 branch (master and new) I made changes in master,Normally I shouldnt see on my new branch .But I can see on it.How can I solve this

Tags: git-branch

Normally, the changes made in the master should not be visible in the branch,but I can see changes
in other branchs, while the changes made in the branch should not be visible in the main. How can I solve this problem?

My expectation is that the changes made in the branch should not be visible in the main or the changes made in the master should not be visible in the other branches